# Contradictory errors in python package VESPA

Tags: exoplanet, python

VESPA is a python package that can calculate the False Positive Probability for Exoplanets. Here is the link to the repository

- https://pypi.org/project/VESPA/
- https://github.com/timothydmorton/VESPA

I had installed it successfully but while importing the package I got an error in NumPy package. I found out that it was due to the older version of NumPy. So I updated it to the latest (1.22.1).

But in that case I got an issue that the another package called Numba wants NumPy of version 1.21 or less.

*I tried for NumPy 1.21 as well but again the same problem.

Here I'm attaching the link to the  pdf that contains the traceback.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KgA0xFAwWrao7KAoOfP7ZDOPQ3AuWyFa/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Before anybody suggests it I'll point out that `Issue #37 Error caused by NumPy and Numba` was already opened 16 days ago with no response there. I'll also point out that there is very little information in that issue, no details or error messages. Without sufficient information there is probably very little anyone can do there. Perhaps you can go back and update issue #37 and add some details. In the mean time, I don't know exactly how, but I believe it is possible to remove your NumPy and then install 1.21. Perhaps someone here knows more about that than I do?

Comment: By all means, update the issue in the tracker with the info you habe. But pretty please, give trace back as plain text or quote it directly

Comment: The dependency on numba comes from the pandas package. numba has several bugs open related to numpy 1.22 compatibility. They're due to be fixed for the next release, but there's no release date for that. You can either wait until they're fixed, or try pinning the version of numpy to 1.21. It's best to do this in a separate virtual environment (`python -m venv myenv`). Within the virtual environment, first do `pip install numpy=1.21` and then install VESPA.